# Unwanted Additional Data is coming with Socket.io and Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, socket.io

**Scenario :**

- When I print out the chat message it adds one extra to the `msg`.
- When I console log them I get this. **Why is it storing in the state an
  extra object value?**

**Console log :**

```
2{"message":"e"}
1{"message":"e"}
2{"message":"e"}
(2) 1{"message":"e"}
2{"message":"e"} 
(3)1{"message":"e"}
```

**Code snippet**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import io from "socket.io-client";
import "../../../Chat.css";
import $ from "jquery";
var socket = io();
export default class ChatLayout extends Component {
      constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
          message: ""
        };
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
      }

      componentDidMount() {}

      onSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        socket.emit("chat message", this.state.message);
        socket.on("chat message", msg => {
          console.log("1" + JSON.stringify(this.state));
          $("#messages").append($("<li>").text(msg));
        });
        console.log("2" + JSON.stringify(this.state));
      }

      onChange(e) {
        this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <div className="chat">
            <ul id="messages">
              <div />
            </ul>
            <form action="" onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
              <textarea
                name="message"
                placeholder="Enter your message here"
                autoComplete="off"
                type="submit"
                value={this.state.message}
                onChange={this.onChange}
              />
              <input type="submit" className="btn btn-info btn-block mt-4" />
            </form>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume that's because you have your `socket.on("chat message", function())` declared inside of your `onSubmit` function. I guess doing that adds a socket listener of some sort every time you submit the form which would explain why the 2nd time you get the message twice and the 3rd time you get the message three times.

**Solution**

Try moving the `socket.on` statement outside of the `onSubmit()` function.

In other words, put:

```
socket.on("chat message", msg => {
  console.log("1" + JSON.stringify(this.state));
  $("#messages").append($("<li>").text(msg));
});
```

In your constructor or outside of the class.

Comment: Hahaha, that's exactly what was happening. Great answer my friend.